# Drawing data obtained from Serial Port progresively getting slower

Tags: c#, serial-port, drawing

I am working on voltmeter application, that draws voltage waveform. Hardware sends 1000 numbers (range 0 - 1023, always whole numbers) in string format per second through serial port.

```
public SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 57600);
serialPort.Open();
```

String is converted into int and then drawn with DrawLine into PictureBox.

```
// variable declarations, all is int, runs in its own thread
while (blToMeasure) // true after clicking on button
{
    iPrevY = iY;
    iY = Int16.Parse(serialPort.ReadLine());
    graphicsGraph.DrawLine(penBlack, iX, iPrevY, iX + 1, iY);
    // only this thread is accessing PictureBox
    iX++;

    if (iX > picBoxGraph.Width)
    {
         graphicsGraph.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
         iX = 0;
    }

    if (iY > picBoxGraph.Height)
    {

    }
}
```

Issue is that *drawing lines itself is fast as it should be only for a couple of seconds, but gets gradually slower.*

I tried `Int.Parse`, `Int32.Parse` and splitting thread function multiple ways using `lock (graphicsGraph)` (moving conditions with Clear into another thread) or using `BlockingCollection<int>` (moving DrawLine into another thread, away from Parse). Nothing seems to work and app still gets slower a couple of times after like a minute of running.

There isn't issue with hardware itself, checked with another software. Is this too fast for C#?

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question. Did you look into the serial port code? Maybe the reason is there, not in the drawing code. Furthermore, you normally are not allowed to access UI elements from background (non-UI) threads. There might be some huge graphic objects allocations in your code leading to memory pressure or handle leaks. Please consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, an mcve can help you help yourself or salvage this question: make sure you decouple the graphics from ther serialport. See what happens when you replace Port.ReadLine() with  Random.Next() .

Comment: And @dymond is right about the threads. Did you disable CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls ?

Comment: @dymanoid Serial port is as it is in the post. I just set portName and baudRate, everything else is default. I tried to measure time between each serial port read with `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` and I get 120-150 (0 in miliseconds all the time) in long term. I still suppose that the issue is with drawing (see next comment).

The PictureBox is being used only by this thread. Main thread starts this one and then does nothing with this particular UI element.

Thank you for that link, I am new here and this was very helpful. :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried that (as stated in previous comment) and also swaped ReadLine for Random, thank you for this! It seems that the bottleneck is DrawLine function. There are several significant spikes when drawing random numbers and it gets gradually slower, too. Lines are not drawn in constant time, it's somewhat fluctuating..

Comment: Try to capture that in a small but complete program. Your picturebox is still a cross-thread violation, something else is wrong (missing) here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, thank you! Tried that and thanks to it, I found sufficient solution.

Comment: If you found a solution, please consider posting it here as an answer. Answering own question is also accepted here, on StackOverflow, if that answer does provide some value for others. If it was only a typo in your code or bad software design, consider deleting your question as not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

I got the best results using `Port.ReadTimeout = 1` and `Port.DiscardInBuffer()`. Also using `Form.DoubleBuffered = true`, but it doesn't make a huge difference in this particular case.

```
// constructor
Port.ReadTimeout = 1;
Form.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Here is the loop itself:

```
btn.Click() // click to start measuring
{
    Port.DiscardInBuffer();
    blToMeasure = true;
}

while (blToMeasure) // true after clicking on button
{
    iPrevY = iY;
    try {
        iY = Int16.Parse(serialPort.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        // exception logic
    }
    graphicsGraph.DrawLine(penBlack, iX, iPrevY, iX + 1, iY);
    // only this thread is accessing PictureBox
    iX++;

    if (iX > picBoxGraph.Width)
    {
         graphicsGraph.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
         iX = 0;
    }

    if (iY > picBoxGraph.Height)
    {

    }
}
```

When the app starts to read from the port, there is always accumulated data, because my hardware is sending numbers all the time, so I get rid of the buffer. Than the drawing of lines is not executed in differing spikes and the speed is constant. Analyzing the issue with `Watch`, I found out, that it occasionaly takes much longer to read this data and because of 1000 reads per second, it slows down. So to prevent slowing down, I used `Port.ReadTimeout`, that skips the read, if it takes too long.

The difference is visible, drawing no longer slows down and it keeps the same pace for minutes from what I've tried. I consider this sufficient solution for my issue, thank you!